# HTTP 404 in Opera and RCurl but not in Firefox

Tags: r, http, firefox, opera, rcurl

I am getting a HTTP 404 when sending a request to a web service on localhost:

```
http://localhost/my-ws/Test
```

In Firefox I get a HTTP 200 OK:

```
GET /my-ws/Test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

In Opera:

```
GET /my-ws/Test HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; en; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0 Opera 12.00
Host:   localhost
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language:    en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

What is wrong here? What parameters to provide to RCurl to get the same result as in Firefox?

Comment: It would be useful to provide the code that you used, so we can recreate what you did as cloely as possible.

Comment: What code? The webservice is provided by a web app I downloaded and deployed to tomcat 7, so, right now, I dont know where to look at...

Comment: For R: I use getURL("http://localhost/my-ws/Test").

Comment: Wildly guessing, but do you have a proxy set up?  If I recall correctly, by default Firefox ignores proxies for localhost, but Opera doesn't.  You may have some odd redirect happening.

Comment: Just checked Opera's settings, there is no proxy set...

Comment: You could try diagnosing it with [redbot](http://redbot.org/), which is especially informative if it is a caching/proxy issue (you can run a local copy).

Comment: I dont know why, but switching the server port to something other than 80 makes the connection work in RCurl and Opera as well, now... Thanks for your support!

Comment: The user agent for Opera is wrong. Where did you get it? from where do you copy these headers? Opera Dragonfly? something else.